# Wrong Header generated by Timthumb Script

Tags: php, caching

I am using the current Timthumb script to generate thumbnails of some restaurant images. I extendes the script, to be have a more effective caching.

The code can be found [here on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/TNjwVb9C)

Changes made:

Line 216 removed the security string, because I do not use the smarty caching system and this lines broke the images most of the time for me

Lines 315 - 345 use a differnet caching path

I use the following htaccess rule to avoid using timthumb and php if the file has been generated once

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_URI} !-s
RewriteRule ^(.*)/service/(.*)/(.*)-(.*)-(.*).jpg$ /timthumb.php?name=$1/service/$2/$3-$4-$5.jpg&w=$4&h=$5&src=http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/$1/restaurants/$2/default.jpg [L]
```

Sadly I get for some pictures a corrupted image as a response.

Original
http://lieferando.de.s3.amazonaws.com/restaurants/12381/default.jpg

Created by Timthumb
e.g.: http://image.yourdelivery.de/lieferando.de/service/13003/Arman-155-100.jpg

the created image has a prepending **jpg ?>** and I do not know where this comes from. Anyone any clue?

Comment: I guess that `jpg ?>` is from script generating thumbs. Maby this script is not parsed as PHP by server, or have some errors. Try looking at PHP error log.

Comment: sadly no, there are not errors in the php error log

Comment: did you tried adding `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the beginig of `timthumb.php`?

Comment: I don't see `jpg ?>` inside http://image.yourdelivery.de/lieferando.de/service/13003/Arman-155-100.jpg

Comment: sry, should have changed the link. I disabled the caching, so that the pictures appear. Here is a link to a corrupted image http://yourdelivery.cdn.s3.amazonaws.com/Arman-155-100.jpg

Comment: @piotrekkr yes i did that. no errors at all

Comment: add `echo("test")` at the begining and at the end  of `timthumb.php` it will show you when `jpg?>` appear

Answer (score 0):

I found the part, where timthumb adds those lines.

```
file_put_contents($tempfile4, $this->filePrependSecurityBlock . $imgType . ' ?' . '>'); //6 extra bytes, first 3 being image type
```

where the variable $imgType is added. I do not really understand the need of that header and why it is only in some of my pictures. But removing those lines did it for me. It seems like timthumb adds some headers to the file, so it will not be readable but by timthumb caching system itself...